# Microsoft Teams - How to find correct tenant?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I've got two ms teams apps - one a tab app, another a bot app.

I'm installing the tab app in an personal role.

I'm installing the bot app in a team/channel role.

The tab app is used by an admin to talk to a 3rd party, get a list of members from the bot app, and then send individual notifications (private messages) to the members via the bot app (with a resource from the third party).

I currently have endpoints on the bot app that the team app is calling (e.g. POST /api/notifications.json and GET /api/members.json)

I'd like these two apps to work across different organizations.

But I'm confused how the bot app knows which tenant it is talking to?  Meaning, if org1 and org2 have bot app installed, how does the bot app know that it is org1 vs org2?

Also, how can the tab app use that same context when calling APIs in the bot app?

Hope all of that makes sense, happy to provide code if it doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: To make your tab app and bot app work across different organizations, you need to implement the necessary authentication and authorization mechanisms in your apps. This will allow your apps to identify the tenant they are interacting with and ensure that the appropriate permissions are granted.

Comment: For the bot app, you can use the Microsoft Bot Framework to handle authentication and authorization. When a user installs the bot app in a team or channel, the bot receives an activity with information about the team and channel. This activity includes a serviceUrl property, which contains the URL of the Teams service that the bot can use to communicate with the specific team or channel. The serviceUrl includes the tenant ID as part of the URL, so the bot can determine the tenant it is interacting with.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Can you point me to some docs?

Comment: I guess here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#create-the-conversation